# how to avoid global variable in python when multiple functions append to the same dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, global-variables

I am looking to avoid using global variables in Python - a bad habit that is now causing be unexpected problems when variable names re-used.

At the movement I load in several large dictionary from csv files (takes about a minute to do). In several functions I then look up from these, and if the value I am looking for are missing, I calculate them (computationally intensive), append them to the dictionary, and save back to the csv files for future reference.

I am struggling to think how I could do this without global variables - I don't want to re-read in the files every time the function is called, and needed to be able to append because often times the same lookup from the dictionary is needed in quick succession.

Comment: Have each function `return` the updated dictionary, and save the results to the original dictionary's variable when you call it, e.g. `dct = compute(dct)`.

Comment: Put the entire thang inide an object.

Comment: Best way to do it is to use a class.

Comment: TigerhawkT3's idea would work well, except you don't actually need to return the dictionaries. When you pass the dictionary into the function, you're just passing a pointer to the original dictionary, because a dictionary is already an object. That's the one that will get changed.

Comment: Additionally, if you are looking to speed up your initial read, you can store the dictionaries as pickles.